# Why the assumption 'L is contained in an algebraic closure of K' is required in the definition of normal extension?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory, extension-field

Let L/K be an algebraic extension (i.e. L is an algebraic extension of K), such that
$L\subset \overline{K}$ (i.e. L is contained in an algebraic closure of K).

Then L/K is called a normal extension if any one of the following holds:

- Every K-embedding of L in ${\overline {K}}$ induces an automorphism of L.
- L is the splitting field of a family of polynomials in $K[X]$
- Every irreducible polynomial of $K[X]$ which has a root in L splits into linear factors in L.

Questions:

> Why the definition assumes $L\subset \overline{K}$? Can we drop the assumption?

---

It is my understanding that, for field extension L/K, sometime it can be viewed as an
embedding of K in L, that is the injective homomorphism of K in L, and K is not necesarily a subset of L. K can be identified as the image of embedding in L.

I dont understand why the definitions require L to be a subset $\overline{K}$ and not identified as the image of embedding in $\overline{K}$. I know that the algebraic closure of field K is unique up to isomorphism.

It may be useful to see that, in this textbook, John B. Fraleigh, Victor J. Katz - A first course in abstract algebra, it always assumes all algebraic extensions and all elements algebraic over a field F are contained in one fixed algebraic closure $\overline{F}$ of F.

I would be very appreciative if someone could explain the concept behind, or provide any reference for me, thank you.

Comment: Sorry, but in your question it is the same in both cases: $L\subset \overline{K}$.

Comment: @DietrichBurde I hope to know why it needs this assumption? Also why not assume $K\subset L \subset \overline{K}$ ?

Comment: If I'm not crazy, if $L/K$ is algebraic it's automatically true that $L$ embeds into the algebraic closure of $K$

Comment: @FShrike Yes, but L is not necesarily a subset of algebraic closure of K?

Comment: It's standard to read the symbol "$\subset$" as "identifiable with a subset of" i.e. there is a field embedding $L\to\overline{K}$. After all, $\overline{K}$ is not actually well-defined. It only makes sense u to isomorhism

Comment: @Tim fields extensions are always (implicitly) defined with an field homomorphism, so $L$ may not be a proper subset of $\bar{K}$ but $\bar{K}$ is an extension of $L$.

Comment: _I don't understand why the definitions require L to be a subset $\overline{K}$ and not identified as the image of embedding in $\overline{K}$._  If it is not already contained in $\overline K$, then it _is_ identified with its image contained in $\overline K$ because we don't distinguish between isomorphic objects... That's what _identification_ means.

Comment: @FShrike I think I misunderstand the meaning of $\subset$ here and the wordings “L is contained in“.

Comment: @ FShrike if $\subset$ mean "identifiable with a subset of", since the image of the embedding is just an identification of L, can we say embedding of L in K induces automorphism of L? Also, we can always extend algebraic extension L/K to an embedding of L into $\overline{K}$, so why the definition needs to mention this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is *not* necessary to assume $L \subset \overline{K}$, and I would *not*  make such an assumption. Instead, I would replace the first of those three conditions with "Every $K$-embedding of $L$ into $\overline{K}$ has the same image".  I think that explains better what the idea is: even if $L$ has multiple $K$-embeddings into $\overline{K}$, the embeddings all have the same image field.

**Example**.  Consider $\mathbf Q(\alpha)/\mathbf Q$ where $\alpha^2 = 2$.  There are two $\mathbf Q$-embeddings of $\mathbf Q(\alpha)$ into $\overline{\mathbf Q}$, and both have image $\mathbf Q(\sqrt{2})$, since $\mathbf Q(\sqrt{2}) = \mathbf Q(-\sqrt{2})$.

Comment: if not assume $L\subset K$, now  $\subset$ mean L must be a subset of K, 
since the image of the embedding is just an identification of L, can we say embedding of L in K induces automorphism of L?

Comment: Your comment uses $K$ instead of $\overline{K}$. In any case, an isomorphism of $L$ with a subfield of $\overline{K}$ is not an automorphism of $L$ just as an isomorphism between two groups $G_1$ and $G_2$ is not an automorphism of either group. But *two* isomorphisms $G_1\to G_2$ give you an automorphism of each group by composing one isomorphism with the inverse of the other.

Comment: Right, it is a typo. Here, let $\sigma$ be the embedding of L in $\overline{K}$, if $\sigma$ is an automorphism of L, 
$\sigma(L)=L$. It seems to me that, $L=\sigma(L)\subset \overline{K}$, so we need the assupmtion
L is a subset of $\overline{K}$. So that is my confusion about the assupmtion.

Comment: All algebraic extensions of $K$ have *some* $K$-embedding into an algebraic closure of $K$, but the embedding and even its image need not be unique (when $L\not= K$). Consider $K = \mathbf Q$ and $L=\mathbf Q(\sqrt[3]{2})$, which has three different images inside an algebraic closure of $\mathbf Q$ (this is not a normal extension). At least for normal extensions $L$ of $K$, its image  is the same for all of its $K$-embeddings into $\overline{K}$. There is not one (“the”) $K$-embedding of $L$.

Comment: You drop the assumption $L\subset \overline{K}$ and replace the first statements to "Every K
-embedding of L into $\overline{K}$ has the same image. But the 2nd, 3rd statements would be changed.
Then the 3 Definitions of Normal Extension are not equivalent, e.g. in 3rd statement, "for all irreducible polynomial
f of K[X] which has a root in L splits over L", cant say that f splits over L, since the image of all embeddings is not L now, 
it seems a big change. For reference: https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Equivalence_of_Definitions_of_Normal_Extension

Comment: The 2nd and 3rd statements do not need to be changed at all. They are equivalent to all $K$-embeddings of $L$ into an algebraic closure of $K$ having the same image.

Comment: Right, we can drop the assumption without changing 2nd and 3rd. Thanks for your help.